# get sum amount related by given amount oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table

```
Table A 

 1. 10
 2. 20
 3. 30
```

I want Oracle query to get when setting 50 return first two records in table A.

and when setting 60 get all records 
and when setting 70 get null.

thanks..

Comment: Why would 70 get `NULL` rather than the first three records?   You should get `NULL` if the value is 5.

Comment: Are you trying to solve [the knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) in SQL? If so, you may find it helpful to read [this blog post](http://aprogrammerwrites.eu/?p=560#.WiT8vbSFgWo)

Comment: I want to get possible sum of setting parameter: if parameter is 30 query get  2 records (10,20) parameter is 40 then return (10,30) and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, sum(t.col2) over (order by t.col1) as running_sum
      from t
     ) t
where running_sum < 50;
```

This will return all records for an input of 70, but that seems like the most logic thing to do.  You could add another condition:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, sum(t.col2) over (order by t.col1) as running_sum,
             sum(t.col2) over () as total_sum
      from t
     ) t
where running_sum < 50 and total_sum <= 50;
```

But that doesn't make as much sense to me.